# "There is no connected blackberry device" Using OSX Lion with Parallel and Windows 7

Tags: macos, blackberry, windows-7, parallels

I'm going a bit nuts trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I got a Mac running OSX Lion
I installed Windows 7 Ultimate using Parallel 6
I installed the blackberry java plugin.

I have a blackberry curve 9300.

I can run my project on the simulator (but it uses so much processing power).

When I try to debug on the device it keeps saying : "There is no connected blackberry device"

When I plug in the device it is detected by my windows but the blackberry desktop software doesn't show anything.

my best educated guess is that Parallel is missing a driver but I've already downloaded the drivers for the 9300 simulator so I don't know what else I can do ...

any ideas ?

Jason

Comment: If you are going to debug on your device, you might as well just use Eclipse on the Mac side.

Comment: there is no support (that I know of) for Macos lion for BB Eclipse on the mac side. when running it under snow leopard, I can only run the code, its not letting me debug because there are no drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem

it seems that you need to download the simulator to get the drivers.

I don't know if you need all the drivers but it's only when I installed the last one that it magically worked